# How can you loop to another different input command, everytime the same response is inputted in Python?

Tags: python, loops

**What I am trying to do, is to loop every time the user inputs 'no' for ''Is it 6 am?''or ''Is it 9 am?'' to ''Is it 9 am'' or ''Is it 6 am'', respectively. The code is supposed to set the temperature to 19 degrees when 9 am and 22 degrees when 6 am**

```
`start = 'yes'
temp = 'yes'
print('Start')
if start == 'yes':
    if temp == 'yes':
        temp_input = input('Is it 6 am?')
        temp = 'no'
        if temp_input == 'yes':
            print('Checking temperature == 22 degrees')
            temp_input = 'no'
    if temp_input == 'no':
        input2 = input('Is it 9 am?')`
```

> This is my program.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me, can you edit the question? What happens if it's 9 am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, when user inputs no both times, the loop will start over again:

```
while(1):
  temp_input = input('Is it 6 am?')
  if(temp_input == 'yes'): #note that Yes, or YES, or yEs won't work in this case
    print('Checking temperature == 22 degrees')
    break

  temp_input = input('Is it 9 am?')
  if(temp_input == 'yes'):
    print('Checking temperature == 19 degrees')
    break
```

This is a very simple solution, you can work on it and improve it

Answer (score 0):

Try a while loop.

```
end = "no"

#Create an infinite while loop 
# - end is always equal to "no"
# so this loop would go on forever if not for the break statements
while(end == "no"): 
    temp_input = input("Is it 6 am? ")
    if temp_input == "yes":
        print("Checking temperature == 22 degrees")
        #the break statement ends the while loop.
        break
    temp_input = input("Is it 9 am? ")
    if temp_input == "yes":
        print("Checking temperature == 19 degrees")
        #the break statement ends the while loop.
        break
```

Example 1:

```
Is it 6 am? no
Is it 9 am? no
Is it 6 am? yes
Checking temperature == 22 degrees
```

Example 2:

```
Is it 6 am? no
Is it 9 am? no
Is it 6 am? no
Is it 9 am? no
Is it 6 am? no
Is it 9 am? yes
Checking temperature == 19 degrees
```